# Existence of the order of convergence of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-calculus

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real number sequence converging to $\alpha$.

It is said to have **order of convergence** $q\geq1$ if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}-\alpha|}{|a_n-\alpha|^q} > 0$ exists and is finite.

If $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}-\alpha|}{|a_n-\alpha|^p} = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}-\alpha|}{|a_n-\alpha|^q}$ diverges for $1\leq p < q$, is there the order of convergence $r$ between $p$ and $q$?

Comment: In the definition it is also required that the limit exists and is finite, right?

Comment: @Gary Yes,it is.

Comment: Do you have any example of $a_n\to 0,$ $a_n\neq 0,$ such that ${|a_{n-1}|\over |a_n|}\to 0\ ?$ It seems impossible. You should allow $p<1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I think you have misunderstood something. The term of order of convergence is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n}|}{|a_{n-1}|}$, not $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|a_{n}|}$.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading on my mobile and took +sign for - sign.

Comment: What about $a_n=e^{-n^2}$ and $a=0$ ? For $p=1$ the limit is $0.$ For any $q>1$ the limit is $\infty.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Ryszard Szwarc's comment:

> What about $_=^{−^2}$ and $=0$ For $=1$  the limit is $0$. For any $>1$ the limit is $∞$.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|^p}=e^{(p-1)n^2-2n-1}$$